# error when creating mobile app on bluemix dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud

I met below errors when creating mobile app on bluemix after setting the name:

BXNUI0005E: The 'olli-app' application could not be added. See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information about getting help.

please see the attached image what the error I got from firebug. seems mobilefirst platform is not ready.

How can I get it fixed?  Any one can help me? Thanks.
[bluemix error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAnTK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This error might be due to some different reasons. Most likely, in this case, it is due to an emergency maintenance on Bluemix platform:
check ibm.biz/bluemixstatus page.
If you should still see the problem please contact Bluemix support.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by limited quote of service. If you create a mobile app, please ensure there are 3 empty slots under your account. the mobile app will involve 3 new services.